# Search from child node text of parent element with xPath

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, nightwatch.js

I'm pretty new to xPath and trying to write an automatized walktrough. The HTML-Structure is like this:

```
<div> << structure i need to search from
 <div>
  <div>
   <ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
     <h1>Month Year</h1> << works
    <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li> << text i want
     <li>4</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Since i try to do it for websites with same structure but different html elements i can't rely on the elements.

What works to get the month with the following code:

```
//*[text()[contains(., '" + month + " " + year + "')] or text()[contains(., '" + month + "')]]
```

but the date won't work. This is my current attempt and i don't know why it won't work

```
//*[text()[contains(., '" + month + " " + year + "')]]/../../../../../../*[text()[contains(., '3')]]
```

Comment: also won't work :( still unable to locate the element

Comment: `//*[text()[contains(.,'Month')]]/ancestor::div[1]//*[text()[contains(.,'3')]]` ?

Comment: that also doesn't work

Comment: try `//div//ul/ul/li[4]`

Comment: untested suggestion: //h1[starts-with(.,month) and ends-with(.,year)]//li[text()='3']

Comment: the problem is i can't work with ul or li elements since the structure of the other websites are mostly tables with the data. so i try a workaround with relative paths that fits all